# converting to a for or while loop

Tags: python, loops

I am try to convet this function by creating it as a for or while loop, but having trouble.

```
def fact(n):
   if n<= 1:
       return 1
   else:
       return (n)*(fact(n-1))
```

this is what I attempted:

```
def fact(n):
   while n <= 1:
       return 1
   else:
       return (n)*(fact(n-1))
```

Comment: Please see [what is wrong with my factorial code in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28475637/4014959) for a variety of ways to compute factorials in Python. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28477818/4014959) to that question provides timing stats for the various approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the above recursive program to use loops is not as simple as changing an `if` to a `while`.

```
def fact(n):
    result = 1
    while n >= 1:
        result = result * n
        n = n - 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a loop, you shouldn't be recursing, you should just multiply within the loop.

```
def fact(n):
    result = 1
    while n > 1:
        result *= n
        n = n - 1
    return result
```

Comment: There is no decrement operator in python (`--`). Change this to `n -= 1`.

Comment: You **can** have an `else:` on a `while` loop in Python!  It's not used much, and is only useful if you have a `break`.

Comment: You _can_ have an `else` clause on a `while` block, but it's not required here. See [The while statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement) in the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for-loop:

```
result = 1
for v in xrange(1, n + 1):
    result *= v
return result
```

Using comprehension:

```
from operator import mul
return reduce(mul, xrange(1, n + 1), 1)
```