# Differences between 'lambda:' and 'lambda x:' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tkinter

I am using tkinter and am confused with lambda functions. The first statement uses `lambda:` in  `command = lambda: Main.new_file(self.pt)`. Whilst the second statement requires `lambda x:`

```
# 1st statement
filemenu.add_command(label='New', accelerator='Ctrl+N', underline=0, command= lambda: Main.new_file(self.pt))

#2nd Statement
self.frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda x: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))
```

Comment: `lambda` is basically just an in-line function. `lambda` can be understood as `def myfunc():` and `lambda x:` as `def myfunc(x):`

Comment: The former is a lambda that takes no parameters. The latter is a lambda that takes a single parameter, and it's named `x`.

Comment: As mentioned, the `x` is a parameter. It's used here because using a menu item doesn't pass an argument to the callback function, but `Configure` events (and others, like keyboard/mouse events) do pass an argument to their callback function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "lambda" mean in Python, and what's the simplest way to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583617/what-does-lambda-mean-in-python-and-whats-the-simplest-way-to-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` in python are inline functions . The format for `lambda` is -

```
lambda <parameter list>: <expression>
```

If your parameter list is empty, then your lambda expression would look like:

```
foo = lambda: print('something')
foo()
>> something
```

You call such `lambda` functions without passing parameters.

If you have parameters to pass to the `lambda` function, you will write like:

```
func1 = lambda x: print(x)
func2 = lambda x,y: print(x + y)
func1(1)
>> 1
func2(4,5)
>> 9
...
```

Here `x` (or `x` and `y`) are the parameters of the inline function.

Answer (score 0):

`lambda x: ...` is roughly the same as:

```
def IDontCareWhatTheFunctionIsCalled(x): ...
```

`lambda: ...` is roughly the same as:

```
def IDontCareWhatTheFunctionIsCalled(): ...
```

You use the first form when the thing that calls it adds a parameter (such as the `event` parameter when using `bind`), and you can use the latter when the caller does *not* pass a parameter (such as specifying a callback for the `command` attribute of buttons).