# how to read the entry function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)
us = e1.get() # doesn't work

def factorize(us):
    product=1
    for x in range(1,us+1): # gives error here
        product=product*x
    print(product)

Label(master, text="Number").grid(row=0)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e1.get()))

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='ans', command=factorize).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add some text, describing the problem you experienced.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The script will insert the the button then it will get the value which is blank 
so you need to move the us to into the function and then remove the us from the parameters this will mean that the value is set when the button is clicked
also you should put some try statement to ensure that the program can handle all inputs

Comment: How will the `factorize` even know what `e1` is from inside the function? This is quite an incomplete answer. You are right about the blank string the way the code is currently.

Comment: you should have try statment that will print a error is a Valueerror is given to the console printing that there was invalid input

Answer (score 0):

Few problems that I see:

-The example code you provided was a mess, that could be due to poor formatting but regardless, I've fixed it for my example.

-You are calling `e1.get()` once, after creating the Entry. This would return an empty string; however you don't actually *do* anything with the stored variable anyway so it's useless. `us` is never used.

-The `command = factorize` doesn't pass a variable, and `factorize` requires a variable. I've changed this so that the callback will pass in the `Entry` widget. In this way, we can call `us = int(e1.get())` *inside* the function, so that every time the button is clicked, we get the newest entry value.

To do this, I changed the command to `command = lambda: factorize(e1)`. `lambda` essentially declares an '[anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583617/what-does-lambda-mean-in-python-and-whats-the-simplest-way-to-use-it)'. It is the only way to pass variables from a callback using Tkinter, because the `command` keyword expects the name of a function, example `command = master.destroy`. Speaking of, I also changed `master.quit` to `master.destroy` because [you most likely want to destroy it](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/66698/exit-a-tkinter-gui-program).

-I've wrapped `us = int(e1.get())` in a `try/catch` block, because you want an `int` for your function. `Entry.get()` will return a string which you can't use to create a range.

-Finally I've imported tkMessageBox so that I can produce a nice error message when you give a bad value to the `Entry` (example, anything that can't be converted to an integer)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

master= Tk()

e1 = Entry(master) 

def factorize(us): 
    try:
        us = int(e1.get())
    except ValueError:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Value Error", "Please enter an integer!")
    else:
        product=1 
        for x in range(1,us+1):
            product=product*x 
            print(product)

Label(master, text="Number").grid(row=0)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1) 

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.destroy).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4) 
Button(master, text='ans', command=lambda: factorize(e1)).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

master.mainloop( )
```