# Python: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when MongoDB query

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas

To make you easier to understand my problem, I will give summary before.

"Today I just query a flat files that I never access before, but the same code work on other flat files on same MongoDB collection."

Below the details,

I have a list to query the `customer_id`, my list it is called `alist`

```
[7068, 7116, 7154, 7342, 7379]
```

I'm doing MongoDB query using `pandas` and `pymongo` on python. Here's my MongoDB query, This is the library I imported

```
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime as dt
```

After that I give the database credential. Here's the credential

```
mongo_client = MongoClient(host= ... ,port= ... ,username= ...,password= ... ,authSource='admin')
db = mongo_client['something-info']
cv = db['flat_something']
```

And here's the Query

```
data = cv.find()
query_filter_alist = {'customer_id': {'$in': alist}}
query_project = {'_id':0}
cursor_list = cv.find(query_filter_alist, query_project)
contacts = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor_list)).drop_duplicates()
```

It is worked on other flat_files on same MongoDB collection, but it is not working for this flat files. Here is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in drop_duplicates(self, subset, keep, inplace)
   3096         """
   3097         inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
-> 3098         duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
   3099 
   3100         if inplace:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in duplicated(self, subset, keep)
   3142 
   3143         vals = (self[col].values for col in subset)
-> 3144         labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
   3145 
   3146         ids = get_group_index(labels, shape, sort=False, xnull=False)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in f(vals)
   3131         def f(vals):
   3132             labels, shape = algorithms.factorize(
-> 3133                 vals, size_hint=min(len(self), _SIZE_HINT_LIMIT))
   3134             return labels.astype('i8', copy=False), len(shape)
   3135 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in factorize(values, sort, order, na_sentinel, size_hint)
    558     uniques = vec_klass()
    559     check_nulls = not is_integer_dtype(original)
--> 560     labels = table.get_labels(values, uniques, 0, na_sentinel, check_nulls)
    561 
    562     labels = _ensure_platform_int(labels)

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_labels()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I guess the problem is on the `flat_something` files, but I guess I need to do several check to understand the exact problem. Any suggestion will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a sample of `cursor_list` and what `contacts` looks like when there's no error or without `drop_duplicates()`. Using this example, the error appears when one of the values passed in is a list `['a', 'b']`:

```
In [2]: pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([['a', 'b'], 'c', ['a', 'b']]))  # ok
Out[2]:
        0
0  [a, b]
1       c
2  [a, b]

In [3]: pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([['a', 'b'], 'c', ['a', 'b']])).drop_duplicates()  # error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

All list values would need to be converted to something [*hashable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14535739/1431750), which is what Python uses to determine that the values are unique for dropping duplicates. Such as a tuple:

```
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series([['a', 'b'], 'c', ['a', 'b']]))  # duplicate

In [6]: df.apply(lambda x: tuple(*x), axis=1)
Out[6]:
0    (a, b)
1      (c,)
2    (a, b)
dtype: object

In [7]: df.apply(lambda x: tuple(*x), axis=1).drop_duplicates()
Out[7]:
0    (a, b)
1      (c,)
dtype: object
```

You would probably need to do this in two steps: first load, then apply+drop:

```
contacts = pd.DataFrame(list(cursor_list))
contacts = contacts.apply(lambda x: tuple(*x), axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

And make sure to use it on specific columns which need it, and not all.

Comment: Ok, thanks, can you give comment on `(lambda x: tuple(*x), axis=1)`

Comment: For that, read about [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). It takes a function to _apply_ to a dataframe, by rows or by columns. `axis=1` specifies _apply function to each row_. I'm using a [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583630/1431750) to pass to `apply`. (See the linked answer for more info about Python lambda functions.) I'm passing each value across the row to the func and `tuple(*x)` uses [argument expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/1431750).